# Migrating Windows Server 2003 Active-Directory to Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2003

I would like to migrate a Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008. I installed Active-Directory on the Windows Server 2003. During the installation of Active-Directory on my Windows Server 2008, there is an error:

> Zum Installieren eines Domänencontrollers in dieser Active Directory-Gesamtstruktur muss die > Gesamtstruktur zunächst mithilfe von "adprep /forestprep" vorbereitet werden. Das
>   Dienstprogramm Adprep befindet sich auf dem Windows Server 2008-Installationsdatenträger im > Ordner "\sources\adprep".

It says something like, please execute `adprep /forestprep` on the Windows Server 2003, but I already did this. When I execute `adprep.exe /forestprep` nothing happens. After this command I need to press `C` and `Enter`. I did this and he executed some operations. Nevertheless the `dcpromo` on my Windows Server 2008 says the message above.

Answer (score 0):

```
--> ADPREP /Forestprep on the w2k/w2k3 schema master (both w2k/w2k3 forests)
--> ADPREP /rodcprep on the w2k3 domain master (only w2k3 forests)
--> ADPREP /domainprep on the w2k3 infrastructure master (only w2k3 domains)
--> ADPREP /domainprep /gpprep on the w2k infrastructure master (only w2k domains)
--> on the server execute: DCPROMO and provide the information needed
```

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9931e32f-6302-40f0-a7a1-2598a96cd0c1/dc-promotion-and-adprepforestprep)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. The Windows Server 2003 was English and the Windows Server 2008 was German. The Adprep.exe needs to be the same language like both servers. Now it works fine.